# RMQ shovel API fails with `Remote Disconnected`

Tags: python, rmq, rabbitmq-shovel

I am using shovel API to perform dynamic shovel in RMQ. The python script to do so fails intermittently with following error :

`urllib3.exceptions.ProtocolError: ('Connection aborted.', RemoteDisconnected('Remote end closed connection without response',))`

API : **http://{host}:15672/api/parameters/shovel/%2f/{shovel_name}**

Using following parameters to the API :

- ack-mode : on-publish
- src-delete-after : {number of messages present in the source queue}

On shovel management window the failed shovel gets stuck and I am not even able to manually delete the shovel. This eventually fills up the memory of the node. Has anyone else faced this issue?